# Вызов функции одного потока из другого

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Как из одного потока вызвать функцию в другом потоке? (threading)
Пример:

```py
def Thread2():
   Thread1.method1()

def Thread1():
   # CODE 
def method1():
   # CODE
```

Comment: Так это не работает. Можно послать в другой поток некий сигнал, а тот поток может на этот сигнал отреагировать нужным образом, например, вызвав нужную функцию.

Comment: А вообще расскажите подробнее что вы хотите сделать, может вы вообще не ту задачу и не так решаете.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я делаю что-то типо RCON консоли для питон программы на сокетах. У меня в консоли 2 потока. Один поток на получение команд из вне и один поток на поток на получение команд пользователем. Мне нужно из потока с сокетом вызвать функцию во 2 потоке для открытия нового input(), ибо после получение команды, консоль будет выглядеть так:
`$ НАЧАЛО КОМАНДЫ command received from XX.XXX.XX.XXX:51240 - reload script ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ КОМАНДЫ
`

Comment: Завесить блокировкой на эвент